# Compiler Error CS0029: Could not implicitly convert to uint

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

There was bunch of question about `implicitly convert` but none of them has sheed me some light to figure this out.

So to speak more about this issue I got.
I am using VulkanSharp bindings in my project. I was writing Renderer code and I have runned into weird anomally that kind of shocked me.

```
            uint _queueFamilyUsedIndex;

            var _deviceInfo = new DeviceCreateInfo
            {
                EnabledExtensionNames = new string[] { "VK_KHR_swapchain" },
                QueueCreateInfoCount = new DeviceQueueCreateInfo { QueueFamilyIndex = _queueFamilyUsedIndex }
            };
```

This part of the code making this difficult:

```
QueueCreateInfoCount = new DeviceQueueCreateInfo { QueueFamilyIndex = _queueFamilyUsedIndex }
```

I did checked what types those variables are requiring and it was weird knowing you did good.

Those are the Classes:

```
public class DeviceCreateInfo : MarshalledObject
    {
        public DeviceCreateInfo();

        public uint Flags { get; set; }
        public uint QueueCreateInfoCount { get; set; }
        public DeviceQueueCreateInfo[] QueueCreateInfos { get; set; }
        public uint EnabledLayerCount { get; set; }
        public string[] EnabledLayerNames { get; set; }
        public uint EnabledExtensionCount { get; set; }
        public string[] EnabledExtensionNames { get; set; }
        public PhysicalDeviceFeatures EnabledFeatures { get; set; }

        public override void Dispose(bool disposing);
    }



public class DeviceQueueCreateInfo : MarshalledObject
    {
        public DeviceQueueCreateInfo();

        public uint Flags { get; set; }
        public uint QueueFamilyIndex { get; set; }
        public uint QueueCount { get; set; }
        public float[] QueuePriorities { get; set; }

        public override void Dispose(bool disposing);
    }
```

As seen those types are correct.

Comment: [MCVE]: `uint QueueCreateInfoCount  = new DeviceQueueCreateInfo();` - please make sure to come up with really minimal example for your future questions. If that would resolve your question before posting to SO it is a good thing... If that line of code does not reflect what you wanted to do/ask - please [edit] the question with explanation of what you wanted this code to do so an answer that does not look like explanation of typo can be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you have defined the field/property `QueueCreateInfoCount` of datatype `uint` while in code you are trying to put object of type `DeviceQueueCreateInfo` which will not work obviously as C# is strongly typed language.

I think your intention is to write something like:

```
QueueCreateInfos = new DeviceQueueCreateInfo[] 
                   {
                     new DeviceQueueCreateInfo 
                    { 
                       QueueFamilyIndex = _queueFamilyUsedIndex 
                    }
                   }
```

You need to use the other property for holding it in array collection as per my understanding:

```
// it looks like you don't need this one there
public uint QueueCreateInfoCount { get; set; }
// but may be you need to use this one 
public DeviceQueueCreateInfo[] QueueCreateInfos { get; set; }
```

Comment: Yes this seemed to resolve the error but I this one is forcing me to change few things in my code bellow this code I posted.